# springSecurityService in resources.groovy grails file?

Tags: grails, spring-security

I'm having trouble accessing springSecurityService from resources.groovy file, I'm trying to load user locale setting and create LocaleResolver

```
import User

beans = {
    localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver) {
        def user = User.get(springSecurityService.principal.id)
        if (user?.settings?.locale) {
            defaultLocale = new Locale(user?.settings?.locale)
            java.util.Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,
Mika

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code above doesn't make a lot of sense. In `resources.groovy` you're supposed to define the implementation class of Spring beans and set their dependencies. It looks like you're trying to actually write the implementation class in `resources.groovy`.

Instead you should write your own `LocaleResolver` class

```
package org.example

class MyLocaleResolver extends AbstractLocaleResolver {

  def springSecurityService

  // implementation of methods omitted, because I haven't clue how you want to resolve Locales
}
```

Then in `resources.groovy`, define a bean of this type that replaces the default `localeResolver` bean

```
beans = {
    localeResolver(org.example.MyLocaleResolver) { 
        springSecurityService = ref('springSecurityService') 
    } 
}
```

Comment: hm, now I'm getting null pointer exception when accessing springSecurityService from LocaleResolver... journey continues

Comment: beans = {
 localeResolver(MyLocaleResolver) {
  springSecurityService = ref('springSecurityService')
 }
}